# Why do I need to add public to this class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class-method

New Rails user here. I get NoMethodError: private method when running Product.first.highest_rating_comment in rails console.

So added public and it worked->

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments

public

  def highest_rating_comment
    comments.rating_desc.first
  end

end
```

Why? I thought class methods were public by default?

[image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcJgj.png)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or detailed error of rails console?

Comment: OK, I edited post, the link to terminal image is now at the bottom of my post.

Comment: It should work. I tried in my local with the same code.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to call the private method is from the public method.

And you are right. All the methods are public by default. So you need not use `public` in the class.

You can learn more about it from [here](https://medium.com/@tjoye20/ruby-access-control-basics-public-vs-private-vs-protected-methods-7788b26e04a7).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working fine.

```
class Product 

  public

    def highest_rating_comment

      p "This gonna print Hi"  

    end

end

Product.new.highest_rating_comment
```

Output :
"This gonna print Hi"